# I see JSON encoded array have 'labels', how do I add these? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array similiar to the one below:

> array("animal" => array("lion", "fish", "tiger)

And I want to turn into the following in JSON format.

> '{"group":"animal","types":["lion", "fish", "tiger"]}'

How do I add the 'labels' such as "group" and "type"?

Comment: You won't be able to  turn that array into that object. You need to reformat your array (`$arr = ['group' => 'animal', 'types' => [..]]`. Then encode it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. You're jumping from "A PHP array" to "A differently organised JSON data structure". What's the actual problem? Is it rearranging the PHP array? Is it understanding that PHP array structure will give you the desired JSON? Is it converting a PHP data structure to JSON?

Comment: @Deepak that would return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array=array();
$array['animal'] = array('lion','tiger','fish');//Your array

echo json_encode(array("group"=>"animal","types"=>$array['animal']));
//Output : {"group":"animal","types":["lion","tiger","fish"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create and format a result array that will allow you to store the datas in the expected format.

```
<?php
$arr = array("animal" => array("lion", "fish", "tiger"));
$result = array("group" => "",
                "types" => array());

foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
    $result["group"] = $key;
    $result["types"] = $value;
}

var_dump(json_encode($result));
```

output :

```
string(50) "{"group":"animal","types":["lion","fish","tiger"]}"
```

If you have many groups, the loop might need to be changed a bit :

```
<?php
$arr = array(array("animal" => array("lion", "fish", "tiger")),
             array("colors" => array("red", "green", "blue")));

$finalResult = array();

foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    foreach ($item as $key => $value)
    {
        $result["group"] = $key;
        $result["types"] = $value;
        $finalResult[] = $result;
    }
}

var_dump(json_encode($finalResult));
```

Output :

```
string(102) "[{"group":"animal","types":["lion","fish","tiger"]},{"group":"colors","types":["red","green","blue"]}]"
```

Comment: I'm curious to know the reason behind the DV